# ARRAY of UUID to raw SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using

```
Python == 3.10 
flask-sqlalchemy == 2.5.1
sqlalchemy == 1.4.46
```

I have a stored procedure `delete_foo_by_uuids` to delete data from `foo` table using PostgreSQL. The stored procedure gets `UUID[]` as input parameters.
It works great inside SQL request:

```
CALL delete_foo_by_uuids(ARRAY['b0f5a699-d080-4f9a-9e68-5d7b397dc4f5', '1026b21a-7ada-4a51-836e-c46579e1116c'])
[] completed in 72ms
```

But I want to run it in the flask python app.
I have tried calling it this way:

```
uuids: list[UUID] = [uuid.uuid4(), uuid.uuid4()]
prepared_sql = ",".join([f"\'{_}\'" for _ in uuids])

with current_app.app_context():
    db.session.execute(f"CALL delete_foo_by_uuids(ARRAY[{prepared_sql}]::uuid[]);")
```

but this way is too ugly for me.

How to make a SQL sentence easier using tools of sqlalchemy?
I suppose something like

```
f"CALL delete_foo_by_uuids({SomePgArrayClass(uuids)});"
```

Comment: were you able to check my suggestion?

Comment: Done. Pardon me for delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sqlalchemy.text` with a bindparam `uuids`.

`uuids` is `list[UUID]` (exactly what you have, no need for pre processing) which you then pass to `db.session.execute` like so

```
from sqlalchemy import text
uuids: list[UUID] = [uuid.uuid4(), uuid.uuid4()]
db.session.execute(text("CALL delete_foo_by_uuids(:uuids)"), {"uuids": uuids})
```

Comment: glad to have helped @DmitriiSidenko no worries about the delay